# How to delete file from project in NuGet PowerShell install?

Tags: powershell, nuget, nuget-package

I am trying to delete a file from a project during the install PowerShell of a NuGet package.

I delete a file that is at the root of the project with this command :

> param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)
>
> $file1 = $project.ProjectItems | where { $_.Name -eq "DebugTrace.cs" }
>
> $file1.Delete()

But if the file is in a subfolder, it is not deleted. To delete a file in a subfolder, I use this command :

> $file2 = $project.ProjectItems | ForEach-Object { $*.ProjectItems } | where { $*.Name -eq "DebugTrace.cs" }
>
> $file2.Delete()

But if the file is in the root or in the sub-subfolder, it is not deleted.

In summary:
- My first example : Deletes a file only if in the root
- My second example : Deletes a file only if in a subfolder

I would like to delete a file that is located in a sub subfolder.

Ideally, I would love to find a method that works regardless of the file location.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
$item = $project.ProjectItems.Item("YourFolder").ProjectItems.Item("DebugTrace.cs")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one please,

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

$DirInfo = New-Object System.IO.DirectoryInfo($installPath) 

$appDir = New-Object System.IO.DirectoryInfo($DirInfo.Parent.Parent.FullName)

$fullPath = [IO.Path]::Combine($appDir.FullName, $appDir.Name, "App_Code\DebugTrace.cs")
Remove-Item $fullPath
```

Change the App_Code folder to your SubFolder.

I hope this code solve your problem.